# font family materialicon not system font

Tags: android, react-native, fonts, expo

My code is using react-native-paper toolkit. 
But not any icons directly.
And not loading any custom fonts in my code.
After the bundle is downloaded, the red screen crash happens.
I running it on my android 8.1. Node 10.4 and npm 6.5.

Please suggest.

My package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^29.0.1",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "~0.55.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint": "^3.17.0",
    "react-native-navigation": "^2.5.2",
    "react-native-paper": "^2.5.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "*",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^4.0.0"
  },
```

App.json:

```
"expo": {
    "name": "AwesomeProject",
    "slug": "AwesomeProject",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "29.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    ...
```

Comment: I'm guessing you are on ios? Follow their manual installation on ios: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons and see that everything in Xcode is linked correctly.

Comment: its android 8.1

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the [instructions of react-native-paper](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/getting-started.html) it tells you that it requires installing `react-native-vector-icons` to work:

```
yarn add react-native-vector-icons OR npm install react-native-vector-icons
react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

Please notice that linking in react-native is often times broken on android so [here](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#android) is the guide for manual android linking of `react-native-vector-icons` for your convenience.